# Is there a way to disable the huge billboard/galleries on websites?

Tags: browser, website, user-interface

Every website nowadays seems to think it is a good idea to have half the page change every few seconds.

This trend is horrible, it either distracts you when you try to read something else, or it switches while you are trying to read the actual promotion it's advertising.

I could block javascript, but that's a bit too extreme.

Comment: Can you give some example? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: http://www.corsair.com/us/

Comment: I'd like to put a screenshot, but it would have to be animated.

Comment: I really think this question is absurd, but i'm going to throw you a "bone." I've never seen any piece of code that does this personally because sliders are could be made out of multiple languages, BUT if there was, you'd need to find what kind of script the website is using, For example that moving banner on the corsair website, is using Javascript and Jquery (subset of JS).

Comment: If you decide you want to disable Javascript off your site, you potentially are going to disable 75% of a website functionality. If that banner was in Flash, Then find a flash blocker. which would likely disable all website Built primary on flash rendering them basically useless. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, "I could block javascript, but that's a bit too extreme." I guess I'm looking for a way to block specific parts of javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One **inconvenient** way to fix that is to open Dev Tools (using F12 shortcut key in popular browsers) and edit the HTML to block it.

In the case of the site corsair.com/us the [hero banner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hero_graphic) is within a *div* whose *class* attribute has a value called *container*

```
<div class="container" id="slide-images">
```

Using the magnifying glass icon within Dev Tools you can find out which is the container that holds the banner images and then block it with a style setting of `style="display:none"` so that finally the original line looks like this -

```
<div class="container" id="slide-images" style="display:none">
```

As the container in a different site may have a different class or id or may be coded differently, it is hard to have a generic solution. The best I can think of is to write a bookmarklet that can take the id or class of a container after inspection of the HTML and block it on your behalf with just a click on the bookmarklet.

Alternatively, you can choose to open links with ["Read Later" Apps like Pocket, Instapaper, Readability](http://lifehacker.com/5894995/bookmark-and-read-later-apps-compared-read-it-later-vs-instapaper-vs-readability) or [Google Mobilizer](http://mvark.blogspot.in/2012/04/google-mobilizer-bookmarklet-view-just.html) which let you focus on the content without distractions.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of ways to disable distracting web page elements but it isn't entirely clear what type you are referring to. Perhaps some example web sites would help us give you specifics.

In the first instance, I would install a good advert blocker. On Firefox, Adblock+ for example. Other browsers have similar tools. These generally use a long list of filters to block out unwanted elements.

You can also add your own filters to ad-blockers though you will need to understand a bit about web pages and how they work under the covers.

You can also investigate "user scripts", the Greasemonkey addin for Firefox for example enables you to add your own Javascript to pages - you can use that to also filter elements on page.